# Can't inspect scope variable when using strict mode

Tags: javascript, safari, web-inspector

When running the following script in Safari (with the Inspector open)

```
window.onload = function() { 
    "use strict";
    var x = 1;
    debugger; // debugger will auto-break on this line
}
```

I get the following error when asking for `x` in the console while being on that breakpoint:

```
Error
message: "'with' statements are not valid in strict mode"
```

Removing the `"use strict";` line lets me access `x` from the console while on that breakpoint.

Both times the `x` is shown under `Scope Variables` in the sidebar.

Comment: I think the error must be elsewhere; it doesn't happen to me [using this test page](http://jsbin.com/acagon) in Safari (I can't set the breakpoint, but I don't get any error and I do get the expected output). Can you post a *complete* replicating test case to the question (and ideally also to http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I can't put my finger on it, but something tells me that you have a `with` statement somewhere in your code... I'm totally guessing here, of course... (Btw `with` statements throw in strict mode code.)

Comment: do you have a 'with()' in your code somewhere else? with() isn't liked and many want it discontinued in ECMAScript

Comment: @MikeSav The decision has already been made. The `with` statement has been removed from the strict mode, and we don't expect it in ES6.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The above snippet is the whole code. I ran your testcase and with the breakpoint set, I get the same error (expectedly). The `console.log` output works fine in both cases, that has never been an issue for me. (It's just there to be able to set a breakpoint in the inspector.)

Comment: [This bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65829) may be the issue.

Comment: @RightSaidFred That could very well be the case! Luckily it works in Chrome, so one can still use the web-inspector with `strict mode`.

Comment: @Timm: So the error only comes when you're at a breakpoint, and you ask for `x` by typing directly into the console? If so, I think the confusion may have been that you have `console.log(x)` as well, so people thought that's where the error was coming in. If this is right, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Yes, I should use `debugger` instead of `console.log` to avoid confusion. Just found out about it through the bug report; will update the post.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue with Safari: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65829

To reproduce the Error, you simply need to type *any* code into the console while stopped at a breakpoint and while in strict mode.

Here's the code from the bug report:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    debugger;
})();
```

So when you're at the breakpoint, go to the console and type `2+3` (or any expression), and you'll get the Error.

[image]

Comment: It says the bug has been resolved but I'm still seeing it in Safari 8.0.7.