# SyntaxError: 'with' statements are not valid in strict mode

Tags: javascript, safari, with-statement, deprecation-warning

I'm getting this error in safari console when I try to do anything from a breakpoint. Bug report here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83267

Does anyone have a workaround? For reasons that I am assuming are related to this javascript has ceased to run on my site in safari.

edit: the bug report also contains repro steps.

another edit: I'm not using a "with" statement. This is a bug from the safari console.

Comment: Not Safari-specific. `'use strict';with(this);` in FF/Chrome produces "strict mode code may not contain 'with' statements".

Comment: It is specific to Safari in that if you try to evaluate anything in the debugger console within a `"use strict";` scope, you get this error, even if you can't see the word `with` anywhere in your script or in what you've typed. Apparently Safari wraps whatever you've typed in a `with` and tries to evaluate it.  See the referenced bug report for more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't inspect scope variable when using strict mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545191/cant-inspect-scope-variable-when-using-strict-mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `with(obj) {}` statement is deprecated, and as such, is not valid in strict mode.

To solve this, either disable strict mode, or stop using with statements!

Comment: I'm technically not using with (safari is internally i guess?) but this is my doctype: <!DOCTYPE html> ... is this what "strict" means in this context?

Comment: Nope. Strict mode is enabled with `"use strict"` at the top of your JS file.

Comment: So I guess the workaround would be to remove 'use strict' everywhere that I can find it until Safari fixes this bug?

Comment: @quinn: I guess so. Unless safari is using `"use strict"` internally as well.

Comment: @quinn: What if you add `"use strict";` inside a function, not within a file? Does that make any difference? That way it should only apply to the content of the function.

Comment: @Eric I removed 'use strict' and everything is working, it seems the safari debugger doesn't work within a context that has 'use strict'; :( thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not the OP using with, it's the Safari console code.

Comment: Why is it depricated? It lets you limit exposed scope nicely without inventing your own less expressive `function using(object, callback){ callback(object); }`. It's nice for `const obj = {}; using(require('fs'), (fs) =>{obj['one']=fs.readFileSync('one.txt'); obj['two']=fs.readFileSync('two.txt')})`

Comment: @Dmitry: Because it means name resolution and scoping rules have to happen at run time not compilation time. No other language construct in javascript behaves this way.

Answer (score 3):

Strict mode in ECMAScript 5 bans eg. `with` statement. You have two choices:

- disable strict mode (remove `"strict mode";` line from the file / function), or
- (preferred) avoid using `with` statements - they are harmful and totally unreadable.

More on strict mode from John Resig: [ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode, JSON, and More](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/).

You can read in the article, that strict mode:

- makes you unable to `delete` variable (like in `delete foo;`),
- limits usage of `eval`,
- adds some limitations to functions (eg. accessing `caller` and `callee`),
- removes `with` statements,

Comment: It's not the OP using with, it's the Safari console code.

Comment: Can anyone point out a recommended replacement for "with"?